# How to fix : "command terminated with exit code 255"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I want to user istio on GKE.
But my istioctl has some errors.

Istio version: 1.2.2
Gke version: 1.12.8-gke.10

```
$ istioctl version
client version: 1.2.2
Error: 8 errors occurred:
    * error execing into istio-citadel-7cbd68dc58-7q4rq citadel container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-egressgateway-76bd65699f-lwrr4 istio-proxy container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-galley-848d6b698c-2kcrn galley container: container galley is not valid for pod istio-galley-848d6b698c-2kcrn
    * error execing into istio-ingressgateway-64d6cfc6cb-nsqb6 istio-proxy container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-pilot-57c9ff7496-4qndd discovery container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-policy-57bf7c4984-z6pks mixer container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-sidecar-injector-9db9b45f5-4ndlk sidecar-injector-webhook container: command terminated with exit code 255
    * error execing into istio-telemetry-bf847c494-7p5hd mixer container: command terminated with exit code 255
```

Thanks you.

Comment: in this case, the exit code 255 is referring to the SSH tunnel. To exec into a pod, the master node will SSH to the worker node and establish a connection to the pod. Do you have any other pods running in the cluster? If so, are you able to use `kubectl get logs` or kubeclt exec` without error to them?

Comment: Thank you for your answering. My error is solving why I dont know .Maybe because I update gke cluster version.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes! It is solved , I dont understang how and why it is solved...